# WebSocket / wss not connecting, used Django Channels and AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: javascript, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels

Getting this webSocket error at site `https://yoga.sightica.com/class/` console. Backend **Django** and deployed in AWS using **elastic beanstalk**.

> **Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://yoga.sightica.com/class/.
>
> main.js:76:16**

or in google chrome

> **main.js:76 WebSocket connection to 'wss://yoga.sightica.com/class/' failed:
> (anonymous)   @   main.js:76**

and this is my main.js file line 76

```
webSocket = new WebSocket(endPoint);
```

I have configured Django channels and Redis elastic cache using their official docs.

```
option_settings:
    aws:elbv2:listener:80:
        DefaultProcess: http
        ListenerEnabled: 'true'
        Protocol: HTTP
        Rules: ws
    aws:elbv2:listener:443:
        ListenerEnabled: 'true'
        Protocol: HTTPS
        SSLCertificateArns: <substituted my ARN FROM AWS CERTIFICATES MANAGER>
        SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
        Rules: ws
    aws:elbv2:listenerrule:ws:
        PathPatterns: /ws/*
        Process: websocket
        Priority: 1
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:http:
        Port: '80'
        Protocol: HTTP
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:websocket:
        Port: '5000'
        Protocol: HTTP
```

This is my elastic beanstalk configuration. I need a proper .config file, other config tutorial are not deploying in elastic beanstalk for me.

i have used this *Procfile* (substituted my path)

```
web: gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --threads 2 <your_app>.wsgi:application
websocket: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 <your_app>.asgi:application
```

I need to get websocket in a HTTPS page, since i need to access webcam.
And the websocket is working in localhost.

( WebSocket() function can be seen here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket )

Comment: Did you open port 5000 in your firewall?, is ping working on port 5000 or telnet?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I also got the same error.

Comment: not  yet, but trying

Comment: @user3486626 **telnet localhost 5000**
Trying 127.0.0.1... 
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Comment: port 5000 is not working, this is the port assigned for websocket.                                             Any idea how to fix.